# Will my boyfriend have any issues at UK border?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, us-citizens, borders, visa-free-entry

My boyfriend plans to come visit me in the UK next year. He is from the US so no visa required. He will be staying with me for 4 weeks in the UK. First 2 weeks, then we will travel Europe for around 3 weeks and then back to the UK for 2 weeks. The issue is, he would have just completed his long term volunteering course in the US so he won't have a job by then. Both me and his family will be supporting his stay during his time here (I have sufficient money) and he will be staying with me at my parents house. We will have all the documentation proof when the time comes. His strong ties to home includes one of his parents who is handicapped and he would never leave as he supports them and a potential job offer from the place he volunteered at. Just worried about the questions at the border as he isn't great with confrentation

Comment: These questions are impossible to answer. He may just get stamped through after the most cursory of questions. Or the immigration officer may get suspicious and ask more probing questions in secondary.  It’s just important to tel the truth and to be prepared.

Comment: I'm leaving it as a comment, as it's anecdotical, but I've been to the UK twice and have never been asked about my job/income.

Comment: Can I ask what questions you were asked?

Answer (score 19):

[From May 2019](https://www.gov.uk/government/news/government-expands-use-of-epassport-gates-to-7-more-countries), US citizens can use the ePassport gates at UK airports to clear UK immigration. It's most likely that he simply won't speak to anyone if he goes through the gates (unless he has something to declare at customs). This is in fact what happens to most people.

He might still need to speak to someone if the gates reject his passport. For instance, if the passport chip is broken or he has an adverse immigration history (i.e. previous trouble entering the UK). In this case the usual advice applies: Answer exactly what is asked using brief answers and don't volunteer information. (If in the rare event he is taken to the back for a secondary interview, that is the time for detailed explanations.)

Comment: They might make him talk on the second trip after Europe as he will have come to the UK twice in a short time... But just be honest and you shouldn't have any problems, do not lie, always comes back to bite.

Comment: @Maya Make sure he carries evidence of his return flight to the US in case he does get questioned.

Comment: "Answer exactly what is asked using brief answers and don't volunteer information"?? Actually, as long as it's the whole truth, you SHOULD volunteer information. A lie by omission is still a lie. For example if you said "I'm visiting someone", while not revealing that that "someone" is actually a girlfriend, then the omission is an attempt to conceal the relationship. Immigration Officers value one thing above all else: complete honesty.

Comment: I'm just hoping that the questions are along the lines of 1. Purpose of trip, "tourism" 2. How long "4 weeks" badabing badaboom. If they ask "where will you be staying?" would "different locations across the UK, hotels and b&bs as i'm travelling across the UK" satisfy them? Which is true, we will be travelling across the UK, including Scotland and Wales. I'm not afraid of withholding the fact that he will be staying with me, but if it doesn't come across is there a need to volunteer it?

Comment: @ChrisMelville Yes, you should mention it if it's relevant, but you shouldn't if it is not.

Comment: @Maya If he's asked a question where it's relevant, then he absolutely needs to mention that he is your boyfriend and that he is staying with you. Trying to conceal romantic relationships is one of the things that triggers border officers. Be upfront about it and you'll have no problems.

Comment: @michael hampton. We both have no problem mentioning it, i'm just aware it may raise more questions, which i'll make sure he's prepared for. I'll also be waiting for him outside, so if any issues pop up i'm there to clarify.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - well yes. Obviously I'm not talking about irrelevant information, like volunteering what you had for breakfast that morning. But in the context of immigration control, the fact that you're in a relationship with the person you're visiting is relevant - and therefore you should be forthright about it, even if not explicitly asked "Is she your girlfriend?". This is what I mean: tell the whole truth (in context of immigration), and you will establish yourself as honest - therefore more trustworthy.

Comment: @Maya - Purpose of trip, "tourism" - is not the whole story though, is it? If you weren't his girlfriend, would he still be coming just as a tourist in order to see the sights? The primary purpose of his trip is, in fact, to spend time with his girlfriend.